# Possible permutations of an m by n matrix given a certain condition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, permutations

Let me preface this question saying that am not a mathematician. I am actually an engineer and my problem came from an particular wiring configuration matrix I needed to construct to figure out every possible way one could stuff up the wiring of a particular device. That being said here is my question:

I have a matrix of m rows and n columns. What are the possible permutations of this matrix given that for each column there must be one and only one '1' and the rest must be '0'.

Or you could say:
What are the possible permutations of the matrix given that for each column there must be one and only one $x$ and the rest must be $y$.

I have been able step through every permutation in an exhaustive sense just trying out every way I could think of with a spreadsheet. But I am really interested in the maths and how I would express this problem. I could probably write a short piece of code to do this but that's not helping me understand the underlying maths.

Here is an example matrix
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ 
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}

This would be a starting condition and the next step might be
\begin{bmatrix}
 0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ 
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}

etc etc

Thanks

Comment: I think the question isn't totally clear. Given a valid matrix, any reordering of its rows will do, so there are at least $m! $, but there are many more valid matrices. What is it you're looking for?

Comment: Would this be correct : For every column m there are n possible positions, the total possible permutations would be m times n?

Comment: Whatever the number of rows, what matters is the number $n$ of columns: thus the number of all possible coluumns "shufflings" is n! (=factorial n).

Comment: @JeanMarie of course that's another possible answer: it all depends on how a "matrix permutation" is defined

Comment: @cronos You are right. Looking anew to the question, I realize that the OP should at least give an example of what he really means by "permutation"

Comment: I put a couple of examples of what I am getting at in the op

Comment: By that example, every reordering of *every* single column will maintain the invariant, so there are at least $(m!) ^n$

Comment: It is even less clearer with the example ! 1) What are the initial condition's)(always ones in the first line ?) 2) What is the rule for the general "next move" described in "algorithmic way" or pseudo-code way. Writing it might help also youself to have a clearer idea...

Comment: By permutation, do you mean taking a $1$ in any column and moving it up or down elsewhere in the same column?

Comment: There must be one and only one '1' in every column and the rest must be zeros. That is the requirement,

Comment: @benguin is correct

Comment: I rephrased the condition requirement in the OP hopefully makes it clearer

Comment: @crowie In that case, you have $m$ choices for positioning the $1$ in the first column, $m$ choices for positioning the $1$ in the second column etc. By the rule of product, you have $\underbrace{m\cdot m \dots \cdot m}_{n \text{ times }} = m^n$ different combinations.

Comment: @benguin thanks for that. It gives me a number of the total possible permutations but I was really looking for a way to express in a mathematical way any particular permutation.

Comment: You could represent the matrices by a vector with $n$ components, where the $i$th component represents the position of the $1$ in the $i$th column. So the first matrix you have as an example would be $(1,1,1,1)$. If you're looking to represent the change from one matrix to another, you could also represent that as a vector with $n$ components where the $i$th component is the change in the position of the $1$ in the $i$th column. So the change between the first and second matrix in your example could be represented as $(1,0,0,0)$. Does that help?